# GAE Jinja2 single quotes escaping

Tags: google-app-engine, escaping, jinja2

**Hello!**

I've attempted to implement typeahead feature in GAE app with TwitterBootstrap framework. It's necessary to render into Jinja2 template this snippet:

```
    <input type="text" class="span3" 
style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" 
data-items="4" data-source='["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona"]'>
```

And it's seems to be impossible because template engine always escaped single quotes replasing it by double. Obviously what entire typeahead construction could not work at all in this case. There are several documented escaping method such as *raw*, *safe* or even *autoescape false* but they can't resolve this issue. How to force Jinja2 to render the single quotes?

Have anybody a matching recipe how it would been resolved?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me:

```
{{ typeahead_data|safe }}
```

Please consider including your actual code next time, instead of just saying 'it doesn\'t work'.